# Javascript - Remap JSON where all prefixed properties are nested under the prefix

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

The JSON data I get from an in house API is returned to me completely flat, but each category has a prefix of the property in which it should be nested under. In the example provided the prefix is `address_`

Example A - Current Format:

```js
{
  name: '',
  address_line1: '',
  address_city: '',
  address_state: '',
  address_country: '',
  phone: ''
}
```

Example B - Desired Format:

```js
{
  name: '',
  address: {
    line1: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    country: ''
  },
  phone: ''
}
```

The actual data is quite extensive, but does follow this same format, so what I am hoping to accomplish is a remapping of `Example A` to fit the format of `Example B`, without having to write out each line of the JSON manually.

Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Will the `_` always indicate the separation of a property name and it's corresponding property? If not, that could be problematic. Also, how does a nested nested property appear, for example (address has a property named number which then has properties of style and type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const input = {
  name: '',
  address_line1: '',
  address_city: '',
  address_state: '',
  address_country: '',
  phone: ''
};

const output = Object.keys(input).reduce((a, key) => {
  if (key.includes('_')) {
    const [pKey, cKey] = key.split('_');
    if (a[pKey]) {
      a[pKey][cKey] = input[key];
    } else {
      a[pKey] = { [cKey]: input[key] };
    }
  } else {
    a[key] = input[key];
  }
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

This will work on only the first level of the `input` object and it assumes that the keys will contain only one `_` character which separates the main key name from the key name of the nested object.

Comment: That actually conforms precisely to the data, I can always add on as needed. Thank you so much for this fantastic response!

Comment: @just_trying_to_learn You still didn't answer two relevant questions which I posed in the comments to your post, what if a property has an underscore in the name? This will not work, also what happens if you have multiple sublevels to a top level property? This will also fail.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't see any questions, but to answer them:

1. The data is formatted such that only prefixes are underscored, the other properties are all camel cased.

2. The data is flat incoming and no property can have more than one prefix, therefore this condition will never be met.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Titus, here is my version that can iterate over an array of objects.

([Working codepen example](https://codepen.io/joss-c/pen/ymJygG?editors=0012))

```
const newJSON = users.map((data, index) => {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((newObject, key) => {
    if (key.includes('_')) {
      const [header, nestedKey] = key.split('_')
      newObject[header] = {
        ...newObject[header],
        [nestedKey]: users[index][key]
      }
    } else {
      newObject[key] = users[index][key]
    }
    return newObject
  }, {})
})
```